# no type named 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std'

Tags: xcode, bdd, shared-ptr, cedar-bdd

Hopefully this helps somebody else

Trying to compile an iOS project with Cedar BDD kept failing with no type named 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' error message.
It was obviously a C++ error but couldn't understand why the C++ library Xcode was using didn;t have the shared_ptr type defined until I discovered the build settings of the target provides two libraries to choose from

- libstdc++ (compiler default)
- libc++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

selecting libc++ fixes the problem see screenshot[image: Xcode 4.4 build settings window]

Answer (score 3):

Apple ship a **very** old version of libstdc++ that doesn't support C++11, so if you use libstdc++ you can't use C++11 features.

Answer (score 1):

In xcode you must use `#include <memory>`, you can not use `#include <memory.h>`. Please check this.